# Задача про списки на прологе

Tags: prolog

Для двух заданных множеств проверить, что каждый нечётный элемент первого списка содержится во втором списике и каждый чётный элемент воторого не содержится в первом. Не могу понять почему мой код не работает:

```
isEvenMatch([], SecondList).
isEvenMatch([X|FirstList], SecondList):-
        isEven(X),
        member(X, SecondList), 
        isEvenMatch(FirstList, SecondList).

isOddNotMatch(FirstList, []).
isOddNotMatch(FirstList, [X|SecondList]):-
    not(isEven(X)),
    not(member(Y, FirstList)), 
    isOddNotMatch(FirstList, SecondList).



program(FirstList, SecondList):-
    isEvenMatch(FirstList, SecondList),
    isOddNotMatch(FirstList, SecondList). 
member(X, [X|List]):-!.
member(X, [Y|List]):-member(X, List).
isEven(X):- Y is X mod 2, Y = 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предикат `isEvenMatch` определяет поведение при получении нечетного числа и при получении пустого списка, однако он никак не сообщает системе, что четные числа следует игнорировать и переходить к следующему числу. Поэтому при запросе

```
?- program([1,2,3],[1,4,3]).
```

при `X = 1` предикат может быть доказан по второму правилу, при `X = 2` первое правило не может быть использовано т.к. `X` не согласуется с пустым списком, а второе не доказано т.к. `X` четный и предикат `isEven` возвращает `false`. Пролог должен пропустить четное число и перейти к следующему, следовательно необходимо добавить правило

```
isEvenMatch([_|FirstList], SecondList):-
    isEvenMatch(FirstList, SecondList).
```

После этого необходимо предотвратить попытки пролога пойти по новому правилу, если нечетное число не входит во второй список. Для этого нужно отсечь дальнейший поиск:

```
isEvenMatch([X|FirstList], SecondList):-
    isEven(X), !,
    member(X, SecondList),
    isEvenMatch(FirstList, SecondList).
```

С предикатом `isOddNotMatch` все аналогично.

Ну и не игнорируйте подсказки интерпретатора относительно Singleton variable. Если замените все неиспользуемые переменные на `_`, то увидите, что во втором правиле  предиката `isOddNotMatch` при проверке `member` вы используете переменную `Y`, а не `X`.

И для сравнения чисел в прологе лучше использовать оператор `=:=`, а не оператор согласования `=`

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, разобрался!

Comment: Можно такой же вопрос, где ошиб:
`insertBackElement([], Element, [Element]):-!.
insertBackElement([Head|Tail], Element, [Head|TailWithElement]):-
  insertBackElement(Tail, Element, TailWithElement).

addEvenValues(_, [], _, _).
addEvenValues(FirstList, [X|SecondList], ResultList, Z):-
    isEven(X),!,
    X > Z,!,
    insertBackElement(FirstList, X, ResultList),
    addEvenValues(FirstList, SecondList, ResultList, Z).
addEvenValues(FirstList, [_|SecondList], ResultList, Z):-
    addEvenValues(FirstList, SecondList, ResultList, Z).`
Нужно к 1 спску + неч эл 2 спска при элементе > Z

Comment: @ВикторТитов, здесь у вас лишний оператор отсечения после `isEven(X)`, условие нечетности и `X > Z` общее и если хотя бы одна из этих частей ложна, то нужно продолжать дальше. А с оператором отсечения при нахождении нечетного числа меньшего `Z` вы не позволяете Прологу использовать третье правило